# Is there a function in DerivativeAPI that can query different parameters?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to know if there is an available derivative api function in c# that handles this endpoint `{urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties:query`? Information from https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/.

What I just found so far from here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/src/Autodesk.Forge/Api/DerivativesApi.cs is a function which only accept object Id parameter.
I'm looking for a c# function (or a function wrapper that calls that endpoint) that can query different parameters just like the endpoint above.

I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint isn't covered by the SDK mentioned, as this was added "recently" to the platform.

You can refer to [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-query-model-derivative-api) with a sample implementation of this endpoint.

In you implementation, you'll need to address it using [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev) or [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0), for example.